# SwiftUI view with optional default parameter

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to replicate the way we can create a function with a default optional parameter in swiftui.

```
func greet(_ person: String, nicely: Bool = true) {
    if nicely == true {
        print("Hello, \(person)!")
    } else {
        print("Oh no, it's \(person) again...")
    }
}
```

Which could be called in two different ways

```
greet("Taylor")
greet("Taylor", nicely: false)
```

Is it possible to create a SwiftUI view with this same logic? I would like to create a component that has a 'default optional' parameter so I could call it as:

```
DividerItem(...)
DividerItem(..., isBold: true)
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here you go... just define the variables of your View, give them default and you can call them with two different intializations

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body : some View {
        DividerItem(text: "Hello World", isBold: true)
        DividerItem(text: "Hello Second World")
    }
}


struct DividerItem : View {
    
    var text : String
    var isBold = false
    
    var body : some View {
        Text(text)
            .fontWeight(self.isBold ? .bold : .medium)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I was slightly confused, trying var isBold?: Bool = true

Comment: Thats two different things. You might declare your isBold as optional. Then it can be nil. Hence, you won't need to declare a default value aswell, as the default value is nil. If you want to make sure isBold has always a valid value, you provide a default parameter without declaring it was optional.

Answer (score 4):

You can create a custom initialiser for your view

```
struct DividerItem : View {
    var isBold: Bool
    // other properties

    init(/* other params */ isBold: Bool = false) {
        self.isBold = isBold
    }

    var body: some View {
        //....
    }
}
```

and then call it with or without the boolean parameter

```
DividerItem(/* other params */)
DividerItem(/* other params */ isBold: true)
```

Comment: What are the differences between both solutions? I personally prefer the first one as it seems less coding. Thank you.

Comment: @jmrueda Mostly a matter of taste and I primarily posted this to show there is another option. And sometimes you might need to have an init anyway for other reasons so then this is usable